# C# Process.Start: Whitespace Not Working Even Quoted

Tags: c#, cmd

What I got:

`Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/K \"C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe\" \"C:/rc/rainingchain/app.js\"");`

Even though I wrapped the filename with escaped ", it still displays the error:

`'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use two " for spaces in program path:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/K \"\"C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe\" \"C:/rc/rainingchain/app.js\"\"");
```

Answer (score 5):

You code will be translated to

`cmd.exe /K "C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe" "C:/rc/rainingchain/app.js"`

cmd.exe will translate it to

`C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe" "C:/rc/rainingchain/app.js`
That's why it complain errors.

What you need is to enclose whole node.exe command with double quote again.

`Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/K \"\"C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe\" \"C:/rc/rainingchain/app.js\"\"");` so the node.exe command will be `"C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe" "C:/rc/rainingchain/app.js"`

BTW, why don't just call node.exe directly?

`Process.Start("C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe", "C:/rc/rainingchain/app.js");`

Comment: Because I need to leave the window opened via /K.